How do you remove this T4 G9-pin light bulb from this Kichler pendant light?
I'm trying to remove this Kichler pendant light light bulb, but I've tried the below actions to no avail:

pulling it (doesn't budge)
pushing it upwards (just the bulb and metal/ceramic base) and twisting it (inner assembly with the wiring twists with it, so I can't grab anything to oppose the twist motion)
looking for some tabs to push in (the white tabs are already pushed in so that doesn't make sense)
looked up the manual from Kichler website but the item is discontinued (I'm going to try calling them tomorrow)



I finally figured it out. Given the age of the pendant light (~14 years), it seemed stuck, so I needed more leverage. Trying to hold the inner socket with pliers was too difficult given the small clearance, so I had to drop the fixture down from the ceiling (breakers/power off) and push in, twist, reset, ad nauseam until finally it came loose!
This light fixture required a G9 bi-pin, bayonet base 50W 120V light bulb.

I was going to say that looks kind-of B15 not G9

You're right. I don't know why the descriptions/spec sheets say otherwise. It's a B15 or at least looks like it.

With bayonet bases the solder of the contacts tends to cold-flow making them hard to remove. apply steady torque, push in, and rock the bulb in a circular motion.
